# creating a UI with a button which will dynamically create .edmx file at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, edmx

i want to create a user interface will should give me the option to select the database from the present ones and accordingly create its .edmx file.

Comment: What did you try so far? Are you expecting someone here to post a code that does exactly what you want?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly if you want to create a program that does exactly the same as the EDMX wizard of Visual Studio ?

Comment: @Levisaxos : you are correct. i need to make it similarly.at present i have started working on it , but am not sure if i can succeed without anyone helping me.

Answer (score 1):

The ADO.NET team released a [Sample EDMX Code Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sampleedmxcodegen) project.

It's supposed to give you enough insight into how the ADO.NET Entity Designer generates code in Visual Studio and hopefully give you a head start with some sample source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.But i am ready with my own code which is fully functioning.